# Print the variable value in a sphinx document

Tags: python, python-sphinx

Imagining that I have a module names `module.py` and inside it, I have a private variable named `_VAR`, I want to print the value of it in my sphinx documentation.

```
module.py

_VAR = 20
```

And in sphinx, I want something like this:

```
index.rst

The value of ``module._VAR`` is :py:print:`module._VAR`
```

And the output would be:

```
The value of module._VAR is 20
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is completely possible to do what you want via the [autodoc](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html) functionality. You just need to make sure that the value is explicitly documented in the code like so:

```
_VAR = 20 #: Notice the colon, this tells sphinx to use this comment as docstring for this value
```

You can then get this value into your documentation by either doing `automodule` with `include-private` or by explicitly doing an `autodata` on just that variable name.

Note that you can use the same tactic (`#:`) to explicitly document the attributes of classes, and they will show up in the documentation for an `autoclass` (or `automodule` since that implicitly will doc the class), including any literal values they are initialized to.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what I was really looking for was just the value, using this, I get the whole variable + value + docstring, is there a way to just get the value from the variable?

Comment: It wouldn't really make sense out of context. You can create a link back to the documentation for the value using a simple ``replace::`` substitution macro around an ``:attr:`` link though. Ex: ``|VAR| replace:: :attr:`moldule._VAR` `` in your globals.rst, and then you just place ``|VAR|`` in your other documentation.

Comment: I was thinking about using the text as the context, but ended up using simply the whole variable + value, should be clear enough. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

If Python had (module-level) constants, such a constant could indeed be extractable by Sphinx by just importing the module. Is that what you want?

I believe that this is not achievable in all generality. What you are showing is a module-level name that would be explicitly declared as a constant in other programming languages (e.g. via the `const` keyword). The value of a constant is not allowed to change throughout the runtime of the program. However, there is no notion of constants in Python (people *use* constants by just not changing certain values, but there is no language feature/keyword to tell the interpreter that a certain value is not allowed to change).

My educated guess therefore is that what you propose is not possible as of Python's lack of constants.

That said, it might be possible to come up with a hack that reads out all values of module-level variables right after import. Putting these values into a documentation might be pointless, since there is no guarantee that these values are correct throughout the runtime of the program.

Comment: The latter, in fact, is exactly what Sphinx does for any variable that is assigned an initial value and explicitly documented (even class attributes).